# Query a Strapi CMS to find blog post by title

Tags: strapi

I'm attempting to query a URL for my Strapi CMS to find a blog post by it's title, rather than ID, so I can link to it in my web app.

However, I can't figure out how to do it, and the Strapi documentation (from what I've found) only tells how to find by ID.

As an example, the following URL successfully finds all of my blog posts:

> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts

The following URL successfully finds the blog post with an ID of '1':

> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts/1

Attempting to then find the blog post with a title of "test title" using the following queries doesn't work:

> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts/test%20title
>
> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts/title/test%20title
>
> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts/test_title
>
> https://localhost:1337/blog-posts/title/test_title

I figured it would be either 1 or three on those above examples, but no luck.

As an FYI - there is an underscore in the above URLs without %20.

Any tips / pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Strapi doc is fantastic and you can find everything:

- You can fetch a single entry by ID (https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#get-an-entry) and you are doing it correctly.
- You can also fetch entries (https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#get-entries) passing also filters in order to restrict the amount of entries you will receive.
- Filters are well explained here: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/parameters.html#filters.

In your case, you should call `https://localhost:1337/blog-posts?title=test%20title` in order to fetch the blog posts with the given title.

Comment: Do you have updated URLs? None of these load anymore due to the v4 docs